# Select 2000 most recent log entries in cassandra table using CQL (Latest version)

Tags: cassandra, cql

How do you query and filter by timeuuid, ie assuming you have a table with

```
create table mystuff(uuid timeuuid primary key, stuff text);
```

ie how do you do:

```
select uuid, unixTimestampOf(uuid), stuff
from mystuff
order by uuid desc
limit 2000
```

I also want to be able to fetch the next older 2000 and so on, but thats a different problem. The error is:

```
Bad Request: ORDER BY is only supported when the partition key is restricted by an EQ or an IN.
```

and just in case it matters, the real table is actually this:

```
CREATE TABLE audit_event (
  uuid timeuuid PRIMARY KEY,
  event_time bigint,
  ip text,
  level text,
  message text,
  person_uuid timeuuid
) WITH
  bloom_filter_fp_chance=0.010000 AND
  caching='KEYS_ONLY' AND
  comment='' AND
  dclocal_read_repair_chance=0.000000 AND
  gc_grace_seconds=864000 AND
  read_repair_chance=0.100000 AND
  replicate_on_write='true' AND
  populate_io_cache_on_flush='false' AND
  compaction={'class': 'SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'} AND
  compression={'sstable_compression': 'SnappyCompressor'};
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I would recommend that you design your table a bit differently. It would be rather hard to achieve what you're asking for with the design you have currently.

At the moment each of your entries in the `audit_event` table will receive another `uuid`, internally Cassandra will create many short rows. Querying for such rows is inefficient, and additionally they are ordered randomly (unless using  Byte Ordered Partitioner, which you should avoid [for good reasons](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/1.2/webhelp/index.html#cassandra/architecture/architecturePlanningAntiPatterns_c.html)).

However Cassandra is pretty good at sorting columns. If (back to your example) you declared your table like this :

```
CREATE TABLE mystuff(
  yymmddhh varchar, 
  created timeuuid,  
  stuff text, 
  PRIMARY KEY(yymmddhh, created)
);
```

Cassandra internally would create a row, where the key would be the hour of a day, column names would be the actual created timestamp and data would be the stuff. That would make it efficient to query.

Consider you have following data (to make it easier I won't go to 2k records, but the idea is the same):

```
insert into mystuff(yymmddhh, created, stuff) VALUES ('13081615', now(), '90');
insert into mystuff(yymmddhh, created, stuff) VALUES ('13081615', now(), '91');
insert into mystuff(yymmddhh, created, stuff) VALUES ('13081615', now(), '92');
insert into mystuff(yymmddhh, created, stuff) VALUES ('13081615', now(), '93');
insert into mystuff(yymmddhh, created, stuff) VALUES ('13081615', now(), '94');
insert into mystuff(yymmddhh, created, stuff) VALUES ('13081616', now(), '95');
insert into mystuff(yymmddhh, created, stuff) VALUES ('13081616', now(), '96');
insert into mystuff(yymmddhh, created, stuff) VALUES ('13081616', now(), '97');
insert into mystuff(yymmddhh, created, stuff) VALUES ('13081616', now(), '98');
```

Now lets say that we want to select last two entries (let's a assume for the moment that we know that the "latest" row key to be '13081616'), you can do it by executing query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM mystuff WHERE yymmddhh = '13081616' ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 2 ;
```

which should give you something like this:

```
 yymmddhh | created                              | stuff
----------+--------------------------------------+-------
 13081616 | 547fe280-067e-11e3-8751-97db6b0653ce |    98
 13081616 | 547f4640-067e-11e3-8751-97db6b0653ce |    97
```

to get next 2 rows you have to take the last value from the `created` column and use it for the next query:

```
SELECT * FROM mystuff WHERE  yymmddhh = '13081616' 
AND created < 547f4640-067e-11e3-8751-97db6b0653ce 
ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 2 ;
```

If you received less rows than expected you should change your row key to another hour.

### Row key handling / calculation

For now I've assumed that we know the row key with which we want to query the data. If you log a lot of information I'd say that's not the problem - you can take just current time and issue a query with the hour set to what hour we have now. If we run out of rows we can subtract one hour and issue another query.

However if you don't know where your data lies, or if it's not distributed evenly, you can create metadata table, where you'd store the information about the row keys:

```
CREATE TABLE mystuff_metadata(
  yyyy varchar, 
  yymmddhh varchar, 
  PRIMARY KEY(yyyy, yymmddhh)
) WITH COMPACT STORAGE;
```

The row keys would be organized by a year, so to get the latest row key from the current year you'd have to issue a query:

```
SELECT yymmddhh 
FROM  mystuff_metadata where yyyy = '2013' 
ORDER BY yymmddhh DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Your audit software would have to make an entry to that table on start and later on each hour change (for example before inserting data to `mystuff`).

Comment: Thanks for your detailed and useful answer! Im trying to work out out (and test it out) now. Thanks!

Comment: @Jacob no problem, just one thing I've forgotten to mention. Don't make your rows super wide. Keep it to be few megabytes (you can test when the performance is best).

Comment: Works perfectly, much appreciated!! Im starting with grouping by yyyymmdd, and adjust as demand requires.

Comment: @Jacob no problem, one more thing you can look at is 'CLUSTERING ORDER' if you plan to always look at your data in 'DESC' order. You can declare your table the way, the latest rows are at the beginning, so it's faster to retrieve it, when the data grows.