# cassandra migration from mysql (design schema for sortable query)

Tags: mysql, cassandra, database-schema, cql

I have a database like that:

- images

  - id (int)
  - name (text)
  - image (blob)
  - create_date (datetime)
  - comment (text)
  - size (int)
  - view (int)

the table images contains jpg with meta information.
I've capability to sort in MySQL (by view, size and create_date)

**How to do the same with Cassandra?**

---

I try some design like:
 - images
   - id (text)
   - name (text)
   - image (blob)

- image_by_size

  - id_image (text)
  - size (int)
- image_by_view

  - id_image (text)
  - view (int)
- image_by_create

  - id_image (text)
  - create_date (timestamp)

but when i don't know how to order without know "id" before...

I read [Select 2000 most recent log entries in cassandra table using CQL (Latest version)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18274007/select-2000-most-recent-log-entries-in-cassandra-table-using-cql-latest-version?answertab=votes#tab-top) but I don't know how to port this to my usage...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution:

- image_by_size

Table

```
CREATE TABLE image_by_size
(
   rowkey text, // arbitrary text, it can be 'IMAGE_BY_SIZE' for example
   size int,
   id_image text,
   PRIMARY KEY (rowkey,size,id_image)
);
```

To list image by size:

```
 SELECT id_image FROM image_by_size WHERE rowkey='IMAGE_BY_SIZE' ORDER BY size DESC;
```

- image by view

Table

```
   CREATE TABLE image_by_view
    (
       rowkey text, // arbitrary text, it can be 'IMAGE_BY_VIEW' for example
       view int,
       id_image text,
       PRIMARY KEY (rowkey,view,id_image)
    );
```

To list image by view:

```
SELECT id_image FROM image_by_view WHERE rowkey='IMAGE_BY_VIEW' ORDER BY size DESC;
```

- image by create

Table

```
  CREATE TABLE image_by_create
    (
       rowkey text, // arbitrary text, it can be 'IMAGE_BY_CREATE_DATE' for example
       create_date timestamp,
       id_image text,
       PRIMARY KEY (rowkey,create_date,id_image)
    );
```

To list image by creation date:

```
 SELECT id_image FROM image_by_create WHERE rowkey='IMAGE_BY_CREATE_DATE' ORDER BY create_date DESC;
```

---

**One table solution**

Since size, view and timestamp are numbers, it is possible to use only ONE table to index all this

```
CREATE TABLE image_index
(
   index_type text, // 'IMAGE_BY_SIZE', 'IMAGE_BY_VIEW' or 'IMAGE_BY_CREATE_DATE'
   value bigint,
   id_image text,
   PRIMARY KEY (index_type,value,id_image)
);
```

To index image by size

```
INSERT INTO image_index(index_type,value,id_image) VALUES('IMAGE_BY_SIZE',size_as_long,id_image);
```

To index image by view

```
INSERT INTO image_index(index_type,value,id_image) VALUES('IMAGE_BY_VIEW',view_as_long,id_image);
```

To index image by create date

```
INSERT INTO image_index(index_type,value,id_image) VALUES('IMAGE_BY_CREATE_DATE',create_timestamp_as_long,id_image);
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is designed to save our days :D. It also saved my day many times